# Why Japanese sender name not displaying correctly

Tags: php, laravel, email, gmail

I am using laravel 9.

My application sends mail when user submits a form. In my local testing, the MAIL_FROM_NAME is correctly displayed as shown in below screenshot

[image: sender name here]

when I test this on server it gives me ???? as shown in below screenshot

[image: sender name on server]

JP Text for testing is コトナル

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the Japanese language packs are installed on your server?

Comment: Thanks for replying. How to check on the server about the language pack? @Aless55

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to encode it first before sending it like this

```
$charset = "iso-2202-jp"; // japanese
$to = encode("japanese name 01", $charset)
```